# After Clearing all the cache. I can't able to scroll to top, menu is hiding

Tags: magento2, admin, cache, backend

[image]

Magento 2.2.7

1. I cleared all the cache.
2. Clicked on system icon on the left side menu.
3. I can't scroll up. but I can able to scroll up after the refreshing page.

Comment: try in private window

Comment: @MohitRane same issue

Comment: you can check it by disabling your module if default is working or not

Comment: give me some time i will check it now

Comment: check @Muhammad Hasham answer

Answer (score 1):

It is known issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6682

One of the possible solution which mentioned in the reference

You need to override this file `vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/web/js/theme.js`

Insert this statement after line 98:

```
menu.css('top', 'auto');
```

**I hope this will help**

Answer (score 1):

Because of the cache in your Web Browser. Press `Ctrl + F5` each time you clear Magento cache to refresh your Web Browser's cache.